# Problem in hardware implementation of cross correlation without xcorr

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

Sorry for any thing silly!
              Matlab uses the built in function called 'xcorr' to find correlation of two signals.In VHDL xcorr is not defined then correlation can be written using for loop the code for which available on below link.But the problem is this code is not easy to implement in VHDL.Does any one know any other way to define cross correlation without using xcorr. Any response will be much appreciated please. Really interested to know the simplest way to find correlation please.

[Cross correlation without xcorr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396814/cross-correlation-in-matlab-without-using-the-inbuilt-function)

Comment: What don't you understand from the discrete-time definition at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) ?

Comment: Stop!  thinking VHDL in terms of a for loop in the conventional sense (NOT a generator) will only complicate things.  VHDL is HARDWARE and you need to think accordingly.  There are ways to correlate in real-time as well as using hardware as a coprocessor.

Comment: For a real time implementation, you can use FIR filters.  For a coprocessor,  you can use DFT and multiplier cores

Comment: Please explain your requirement and I can provide an answer

Comment: @johnnymopo Thanks for your reply. I have two vectors lets say x1=[2 3 4 5 6 6.6 5.5 4.4] and  x2=[4.4 5.5 6.6 6 5 4 3 2] and want to find delay between them using correlation.In Matlab I have  done it but when I try to convert it into VHDL using HDL Coder it gives me error.Can you please explain how I can do it.

Comment: My actual signals are longer .These are just sample vector.Kindly I would really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @PeterK. Thanks for posting the link.understanding the correlation theory is not a problem . the problem is to find the simplest code to convert into VHDL using HDL Coder.

Comment: HDL Coder is new information.  A quick search shows problems with for/while loops but I can't help you with Matlab code generation.  I assume if you pay $20k for something they would assist you.  You could try using DFTs to do cross correlation without a for loop.